# How to use powerpoint vba, Paste the contents as plain text of the clipboard after the current text, currently environment office365

Tags: vba, powerpoint

This is the function I want. 
**Paste the contents as plain text of the clipboard after the current text**

The following code works

```
ActiveWindow.View.Slide _
.Shapes.Placeholders.Item(3).TextFrame.TextRange.InsertAfter "ttt" 

'InsertAfter seems Accept only strings
```

The following code works

```
ActiveWindow.Activate
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")'pasting as plain text
```

---

Although it comes from the 
https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/office/vba/api/powerpoint.textrange.insertafter

The following code does not work

```
ActiveWindow.View.Slide _
.Shapes.Placeholders.Item(3).TextFrame.TextRange.InsertAfter.Paste

'This is the function I want.
'Paste the contents as plain text of the clipboard after the current text
```

The following code does not work

```
ActiveWindow.View.Slide _
.Shapes.Placeholders.Item(3).TextFrame.TextRange.InsertAfter.PasteSpecial ppPasteText

'ref https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bGiAZZk6LlI
```

I wish it could be
I have tried the following codes, but not work.

```
ActiveWindow.View.Slide _
.Shapes.Placeholders.Item(3).TextFrame.TextRange.InsertAfter.
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteTextOnly") 'pasting as plain text
```

---

---

---

After I ran it, 
I got the following result.
[Execution Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/If1nE.png)

---

[Before program execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Njod.png)

---

my clipboard text is "SlideMaster Modify"
[The result of the program execution I want is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f78b5.png)

Comment: When your only comment is "works" or "does not work", there's not much we can write to help you. You've posted 2 items where you write "works". Okay so what's the problem? Post a description of what results you get and how you want those results improved.

Comment: Yes, Mr. Korchok <br/>
I reply in the following paragraphs.

Comment: Yes, Mr. Korchok.

I found the answer
I refer to here for the answer - Thank you very much
https://www.office-forums.com/threads/ppt-2007-bug.177297/

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer
I refer to here for the answer - Thank you very much
https://www.office-forums.com/threads/ppt-2007-bug.177297/

The following code works

```
ActiveWindow.View.Slide _
.Shapes.Placeholders.Item(3).TextFrame.TextRange.InsertAfter (vbLf)
'Line break


ActiveWindow.View.Slide _
.Shapes.Placeholders.Item(3).TextFrame.TextRange.InsertAfter(" ").PasteSpecial ppPasteText
'Paste Text Only
'ref https://www.office-forums.com/threads/ppt-2007-bug.177297/
```